Simulating the time needed for a Random Walk to reach a certain point
I am trying to simulate a random walk in R, and find out the average time needed to reach a certain point for the first time. Then, I repeat this simulation multiple times and plot the distribution of the results.
Here is the code I am using:
set.seed(123)

# I used many iterations, but feel free to make this 100 to run faster
n_iterations <- 100000
n_steps <- 100

simulate_walk <- function() {
    walk <- cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n_steps, replace = TRUE))
    first_encounters <- sapply(unique(walk), function(pos) min(which(walk == pos)))
    return(data.frame(position = unique(walk), first_encounter = first_encounters))
}

all_encounters <- replicate(n_iterations, simulate_walk(), simplify = FALSE)

result <- do.call(rbind, all_encounters)

summary_data <- result %>%
    group_by(position) %>%
    summarize(
        mean_encounter = mean(first_encounter),
        median_encounter = median(first_encounter),
        q25 = quantile(first_encounter, 0.25),
        q75 = quantile(first_encounter, 0.75)
    )

ggplot(summary_data, aes(x = position, y = median_encounter)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = q25, ymax = q75), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = "Distribution of First Encounter Times for Each Position",
         x = "Position",
         y = "Steps to First Encounter") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) 

My question is the following - when I look at the results of the simulation:

Logically, these "dips" (in the red circles) do not make sense to me. A random walk is symmetric and it should take more and more time on average to reach points that a further out. This makes me think that my logic is not correct.
Can someone help me fix this?

Many of the simulations won't reach the extremes, so what you're actually plotting is the average time to reach that position among those simulations that reach the position in less than n_steps. To get the information you want for a range from -n to n, you need to run the simulations for long enough that every simulation reaches -n and n, otherwise these times are under-estimated.

@Miff : AH, i understand! thank you so much for pointing this out!

As an aside, you can calculate first encounters much more efficiently using first_encounters <- match(unique(walk), walk).

@lroha : thank you for this ... can you please post an answer if you have time?

@heartofdarkness - it's not an answer to your question, just a minor optimization to your code so will leave it as a comment. Questions here should be narrowly focused.

You need to limit the boundary for the position when you plot the graph, or increase the value for nsteps if you want a wider boundary.
From your graph, the positions where the lines start to 'dip' correspond to the positions where the interquartile ranges begin to "thin out" due to fewer samples. For a value of nsteps equal to 100, your graph should be limited to about +/- 16 on the x-axis.
ggplot(...) + ...
coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-16, 16))


If nsteps is increased to 1000, the inter-quartile range begins to thin out around the +/- 50 mark.


thank you so much!
